# Iterating through object array in $scope and updating it

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of objects in the scope (`$scope.contracts`). When I run my function, I pass in a contract. I Want it to iterate through `$scope.contracts` and find the one with the same .CONT_ORDNO. Then I want to set this contract to the contract passed in.

```
    $scope.mergeContract = function (contractThatsReplaced) {//clicked 2nd new
        angular.forEach($scope.contracts, function (con) {
            if (con.CONT_ORDNO == contractThatsReplaced.CONT_ORDNO) {
                con = $scope.contractToMerge;
            }
        });
    };
```

Here is me trying to do it, it does everything I want except that only the con variable is changed, the actual contract that's an array location in `$scope.contracts` is not being updated. How do I make sure it is?

Note I don't want to remove and replace the contract, I want to update it.

Edit: I updated the if statement to have two (==). This doesn't fix it. It still is only setting the con variable correctly, not the `$scope.contracts` array location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning to `con` only changes the local variable. Try this instead:

```
$scope.mergeContract = function (contractThatsReplaced) {//clicked 2nd new
    angular.forEach($scope.contracts, function (con, i) {
        if (con.CONT_ORDNO == contractThatsReplaced.CONT_ORDNO) {
            $scope.contracts[i] = $scope.contractToMerge;
        }
    });
};
```

Also, you need to change `=` to `==` in the `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

need `==` in the if condition

```
if (con.CONT_ORDNO == contractThatsReplaced.CONT_ORDNO) {
```

Comment: The if statement was breaking inside but I'll check if this changes things.

Comment: = means assignment; == and === mean comparison and exact comparison (i.e types are also compared).

Comment: This has no effect. Still, only the con variable is being set, not the $scope.contracts array location.